# get data immediately in angularjs using $http or $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i created a plug-in for field

```
angular.module('ersProfileForm').directive('ersProfileEditableField', ['$templateCache', '$compile', 'profileFieldService', 'RolesService',
                                                           function($templateCache,   $compile,   profileFieldService , RolesService){
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl: '',
    scope: {
        ersProfileEditableField: '=',
        ersProfileSectionData: '=',
        ersProfileEditableFieldValue: '=',
        ersBulkEdit: '<'
    },
    controller: ['$scope', '$http','$q','$resource', function($scope, $http, $q, $resource){
        $http.get('rest/roles',{}).then(function(response){
            $scope.roles = response.data;
        }); 

    }],
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller){
        iElement.append(jQuery(profileFieldService.getTemplate(scope.ersProfileEditableField.type, scope)));
        $compile(iElement.contents())(scope);
    }
};
}]);
```

roles data will be used in this template

```
 angular.module('ersProfileForm').factory('profileFieldService', ['$resource', function($resource){
var factory = {};
factory.getTemplate = function(type, scope){
    scope.field = scope.ersProfileEditableField; 
    var tpl = '<div ng-repeat ="role in roles"'> 
            +' <label>{{role.name</label>'
            +' </div>'
        break;
return tpl;
};
return factory;
}]);
```

i want roles array in this template but service is taking time so roles is  not defined in template it is executing after some time

**my question is that i want roles data from the request only then go to template which is defined in link?**

Comment: you need to call the template once data received, so move the function call `getTemplate` right after your `$scope.roles` at the moment the `link` bit gets called before the data is returned from your call.

Comment: i am not understanding it getTemplate can not be defined in controller after the $scope.roles it should be defined in link

Comment: Last comment makes no sense. Also makes no sense to use jQuery for this. Why do you even need a factory for the template?

Comment: it is big plug-in i have created it in short form i dont know why gave me negative vote

Answer (score 0):

Try `var tpl = '<div ng-repeat ="role in roles" ng-show="roles&&(roles.length>0)"> '+' <label>role.name</label>' +' </div>'`

Comment: get data from the request only then go to template which is defined in link

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using the $q promise object ? resolve it in your $http method, then use it with     .then :)
Here is a link from the docs :
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: ya i have used it own way provide some code whatever  you want to say?

Answer (score 0):

The template needs double curly brackets `{{ }}` to bind data to the DOM:

```
factory.getTemplate = function(type, scope){
    scope.field = scope.ersProfileEditableField; 
    var tpl = '<div ng-repeat ="role in roles"'> 
          // +' <label>role.name</label>'
          // USE {{ }} for interpolation
            +' <label>{{role.name}}</label>'
            +' </div>'
    return tpl;
};
```

---

The compile can be delayed by using a watcher:

```
link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller){
    scope.$watch("::roles", function (newValue) {
        if (newValue) {
            iElement.append(
                profileFieldService
                    .getTemplate(scope.ersProfileEditableField.type, scope)
            );
            $compile(iElement.contents())(scope);
        };
    });
}
```

The watcher waits for the `roles` data that is fetched from the server before doing the compile. It uses a [one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) so that the compile is performed only once but the `ng-repeat` directive will continue to update the DOM as the value of `roles` changes.

Comment: that was the mistake i have updated but it is not the answer